# Content going under the header at first run

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-relativelayout

A part of my app which is an activity that shows order details has main NestedScrollViewlayout and it is under the AppBarLayout. the problem is that the NestedScrollViewlayout  going under the AppBarLayout at the first run So I also have added app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to the NestedScrollViewlayout but i haven't gotten any luck.

this is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="right|center"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="right|bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"


            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productImage_Single_Suggest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/loginbg_opt"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"

        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_name_suggest_single"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/items"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="باقله تبریزی اعلا "
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="نام محصول:"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_code_suggest_single"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_name_suggest_single"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/items"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="2122"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="کد محصول"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_count_suggest_single"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_code_suggest_single"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/items"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="1111"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="موجودی انبار:"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/txtSuggestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_count_suggest_single"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/items"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="پیشنهاد"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text=" ژنرال ارتش ترکیه روز چهارشنبه ۳۰ تیرماه رسما به تلاش برای انجام کودتا در این کشور متهم شدند. همزمان، ۲۶۲ قاضی و دادستان دادگاه‌های نظامی و ۹۰۰ پلیس در آنکارا پایتخت ترکیه نیز از سمت خود تعلیق شده‌اند.

شش هزار و ۵۰۰ نفر دیگر از کارکنان وزارت آموزش ملی این کشور نیز از سمت‌های خود تعلیق شده‌اند. این اقدام یک روز پس از اخراج بیش از ۱۵ هزار معلم از سوی این وزارتخانه صورت می‌گیرد.

دولت ترکیه روز سه‌شنبه همچنین مجوز تدریس ۲۱ هزار معلم شاغل در بخش خصوصی را لغو کرده بود.

با احتساب این ارقام، تاکنون بیش از ۶۰ هزار قاضی، معلم، سرباز، پلیس و کارمند دولت از کار خود تعلیق شده‌اند." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/txtreplayToSuggestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtSuggestion"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/items"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="پاسخ به پیشنهاد"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text=" ژنرال ارتش ترکیه روز چهارشنبه ۳۰ تیرماه رسما به تلاش برای انجام کودتا در این کشور متهم شدند. همزمان، ۲۶۲ قاضی و دادستان دادگاه‌های نظامی و ۹۰۰ پلیس در آنکارا پایتخت ترکیه نیز از سمت خود تعلیق شده‌اند.

شش هزار و ۵۰۰ نفر دیگر از کارکنان وزارت آموزش ملی این کشور نیز از سمت‌های خود تعلیق شده‌اند. این اقدام یک روز پس از اخراج بیش از ۱۵ هزار معلم از سوی این وزارتخانه صورت می‌گیرد.

دولت ترکیه روز سه‌شنبه همچنین مجوز تدریس ۲۱ هزار معلم شاغل در بخش خصوصی را لغو کرده بود.

با احتساب این ارقام، تاکنون بیش از ۶۰ هزار قاضی، معلم، سرباز، پلیس و کارمند دولت از کار خود تعلیق شده‌اند." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtreplayToSuggestion"
                android:text="ارسال ایمیل" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and also my app pic at first run:

[image]

Comment: Try switching your `NestedScrollView` with your `FloatingActionButton`. This will make your `FloatingActionButton` appear above your scrolling content, and it *may* fix the scrolling content appearing under the `ActionBarLayout` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Give this code a try and see if it works for you i have removed the background from the code you have posted as i dont have the `drawables` you can add it if my code works

**MyActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productImage_Single_Suggest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/loginbg_opt"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_of_my_activity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_of_my_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MyActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">


        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_name_suggest_single"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="باقله تبریزی اعلا "
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="نام محصول:"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_code_suggest_single"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_name_suggest_single"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="2122"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="کد محصول"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_count_suggest_single"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_code_suggest_single"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="1111"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="موجودی انبار:"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/txtSuggestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_count_suggest_single"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="پیشنهاد"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text=" ژنرال ارتش ترکیه روز چهارشنبه ۳۰ تیرماه رسما به تلاش برای انجام کودتا در این کشور متهم شدند. همزمان، ۲۶۲ قاضی و دادستان دادگاه‌های نظامی و ۹۰۰ پلیس در آنکارا پایتخت ترکیه نیز از سمت خود تعلیق شده‌اند.

شش هزار و ۵۰۰ نفر دیگر از کارکنان وزارت آموزش ملی این کشور نیز از سمت‌های خود تعلیق شده‌اند. این اقدام یک روز پس از اخراج بیش از ۱۵ هزار معلم از سوی این وزارتخانه صورت می‌گیرد.

دولت ترکیه روز سه‌شنبه همچنین مجوز تدریس ۲۱ هزار معلم شاغل در بخش خصوصی را لغو کرده بود.

با احتساب این ارقام، تاکنون بیش از ۶۰ هزار قاضی، معلم، سرباز، پلیس و کارمند دولت از کار خود تعلیق شده‌اند." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/txtreplayToSuggestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtSuggestion"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="پاسخ به پیشنهاد"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text=" ژنرال ارتش ترکیه روز چهارشنبه ۳۰ تیرماه رسما به تلاش برای انجام کودتا در این کشور متهم شدند. همزمان، ۲۶۲ قاضی و دادستان دادگاه‌های نظامی و ۹۰۰ پلیس در آنکارا پایتخت ترکیه نیز از سمت خود تعلیق شده‌اند.

شش هزار و ۵۰۰ نفر دیگر از کارکنان وزارت آموزش ملی این کشور نیز از سمت‌های خود تعلیق شده‌اند. این اقدام یک روز پس از اخراج بیش از ۱۵ هزار معلم از سوی این وزارتخانه صورت می‌گیرد.

دولت ترکیه روز سه‌شنبه همچنین مجوز تدریس ۲۱ هزار معلم شاغل در بخش خصوصی را لغو کرده بود.

با احتساب این ارقام، تاکنون بیش از ۶۰ هزار قاضی، معلم، سرباز، پلیس و کارمند دولت از کار خود تعلیق شده‌اند." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtreplayToSuggestion"
                android:text="ارسال ایمیل" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap FloatingActionButton and NestedScrollView. So you will have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="right|center"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="right|bottom"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"


        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productImage_Single_Suggest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/loginbg_opt"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_name_suggest_single"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/items"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="باقله تبریزی اعلا "
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="نام محصول:"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_code_suggest_single"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_name_suggest_single"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/items"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="2122"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="کد محصول"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_count_suggest_single"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_code_suggest_single"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/items"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="1111"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="موجودی انبار:"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtSuggestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_count_suggest_single"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/items"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="پیشنهاد"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="some text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtreplayToSuggestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSuggestion"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/items"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="پاسخ به پیشنهاد"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text=" some text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtreplayToSuggestion"
            android:text="ارسال ایمیل" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/user"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thank u for your replay, but it is not my answer. i copied and pasted to my xml layout and see it seems to work but i can not fill my text with content and when i fill the text with content. i get the same thing as i said in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood, what did you mean by "not my answer"? About code, if you go through tutorials, FloatingActionButton in most cases placed in the end of xml. Here is an example http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: yes you are right, but the problem isn't floatingActionButton, i also removed floatingActionButton but i get same

Comment: Why in your header image view you have collapseMode `pin` instead of `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"`?

Comment: So, did this fix issue?

Comment: of course it doesn't fix the issue and i also tested it make sure